# tar exits on "Cannot stat: No such file of directory", why?

Tags: tar

I'm trying to create tar.gz file using the following command:

```
sudo tar -vcfz dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz dvr_rdk/
```

It then start to create files (many files in folder), but then I get the following error:

```
tar: dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I don't see any description of this error, what does it mean?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Remove `-` from `vcfz` options. `tar` does not need hyphen for options.

With a hyphen, the argument for the `-f` option is `z`. So the command is in effect trying to archive `dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz` and `dvr_rdk` into an archive called `z`. Without the hyphen, the semantics of the options changes, so that the next argument on the command line, i.e. your archive's filename, becomes the argument to the `f` flag.

Also check your write permission to the directory from which you are executing the command.

Comment: It doesn't *need* hyphens, but they shouldn't be a problem, they're just optional

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Actually, removing the `-` does make a difference, because GNU tar is quirky. Option arguments can't be bundled in the first argument when it doesn't start with a `-`, so the argument to `f` is the next argument to `tar`, and so `tar vcfz dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz` is equivalent to `tar -v -c -f dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz -z`.

Comment: I also realized if I remove the `z` or `j` the archive compression is successful even with `-` involved. When I add the hyphen is included it treats the last character in the option as a "file". So as a result I get `j` or `z` as an archived file if I use this option `-cvfz` or `-cvfj`.

Comment: **Summary:** if 'f' occurs as an option anywhere other as than the last option, then the command will not do what was intended. I don't see how Gnu couldn't add a warning when they detect such a serious and easily-detectable issue. I just spent 40min trying to debug this weirdness. This one must have wasted hundreds of thousands of man-hours of productivity.

Comment: I had to remove the hyphen to make it work, although I have used the hyphen many times on other systems. Can't they just keep the syntax consistent??!

Comment: `tar` is my least favorite cli tool. Why is it the way it is?

Answer (score 86):

The `-f` option should directly precede the filename. So, use `tar -vczf filename.tar.gz` instead of `-vcfz`

Comment: Ah this explains why the command I'm using tries to create a compressed archive file called `j` or `z` with these commands `-cvfj` and  `-cvfz` respectively.

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 19):

The [tar command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html) historically has been one of the few commands that doesn't follow the Unix [utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02).

The standards page for tar says:

> f
>   Use the first file operand (or the second, if b has already been specified) as the name of the archive instead of the system-dependent default

While the syntax guidelines include this:

> Guideline 5:
>   One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter.

So while the command you typed, `tar -vcfz dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz dvr_rdk/`, would be fine on older versions of tar, certain versions of tar that are written to strictly follow the utility syntax guidelines will parse this to mean "use `z` as the file argument to `-f`". So you should use the following to be portable:

```
tar -cvzf dvr_rdk_v1.tar.gz dvr_rdk/
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the `-f` needs to go immediately before the archive name
but after the `--exclude` options in this Makefile multi-line example...

```
-f $(HOME)/.bitcoin-$(TIME).tar.gz $(HOME)/.bitcoin'
```

#######################
#Backup $HOME/.bitcoin - Makefile usage example
########################

```
TIME=$(shell date +%s)  
export TIME  
init:  
    @echo ''  
    bash -c 'mkdir -p $(HOME)/.bitcoin'  
    bash -c 'conf/get_size.sh'  
    bash -c 'tar czv --exclude=*.log --exclude=banlist.dat \  
            --exclude=fee_exstimates.dat --exclude=mempool.dat \  
            --exclude=peers.dat --exclude=.cookie \  
            --exclude=.lock --exclude=.walletlock \  
            -f $(HOME)/.bitcoin-$(TIME).tar.gz $(HOME)/.bitcoin'  
    #install current bitcoin.conf  
    bash -c 'install -v conf/bitcoin.conf $(HOME)/.bitcoin'  
    @echo ''
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254164/getting-an-error-cp-cannot-stat-when-trying-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-an) was the answer for me.  Keep wildcards outside the quotes: `tar -zcf archive.tar.gz "file-0"*`